# the grammatical roles of "at most"

Tags: dictionaries

I just looked up "at (the) most" in "Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English". It was under the entry for "most" as determiner and/or pronoun. One of the example sentences for it in the dictionary is:

> It’ll take 20 minutes at the most.

But I feel its role is like an adverb. For example in the above sentence it seems that it adds more information to the verb, exactly the function of adverbs. Am I right?

Any response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the description as 'determiner or pronoun' applies to the word 'most' *within* the prepositional phrase 'at most'. That phrase itself is adverbial, applying to a clause or sentence.
 [A mention of similar phrases.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44950/grammatical-function-of-at-best-idiom)
The second answer at that link is particularly informative.

Comment: If it's not a determiner and/or preposition, why is it within that entry?

Comment: Did you read the link already? As to why something is as it is in Longman dictionary, ask them!.

Comment: I read the link. I was my answer. Anyway, I thought you could help me with Longman's logic, too. Thank you.